# How to resolve useMemo output

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to get an output of useMemo result:

```
const output=useMemo(()=>{
    let output=(async function () {
        await getPlantInfoById(itemId)
            .then(item => {
                return item;
            })
    })();
    return output;
},[itemId])
```

But when I track the output variable via inspect element:

```
console.log(output)
```

It prints pending.

Why? How to get a preferred result?

Comment: in this case useMemo returns a promise. So it does exactly what you are telling it to do.

Comment: Since useEffect is used previously for component initial loading purposes. It cant be used now. But I want to use useMemo instead. because when some data changes.

Answer (score 3):

`useMemo` cannot be used to resolve asychronous values. But this behavior can be replicated using the `useState` and `useEffect` hooks:

```
const [plantData, setPlantData] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
    getPlantInfoById(itemId).then(setPlantData);
}, [itemId]);
```

Comment: Since useEffect is used previously for component initial loading purposes. It cant be used now. But I want to use useMemo instead. because when some data changes.

Comment: You can use `useEffect` as many times you want.

Comment: @albert If useEffect cannot be used, please share the reason why, your current reasoning is invalid. Ideally share a minimal reproducible example of the current behavior. Using `useMemo` is not a valid way of resolving promises. Async/await is just syntactic sugar for working with promises, basically, marking a function as async wraps the return value in a promise and  `await` can be thought of as pretty much chaining `.then` handlers to the existing promise. As components are synchronous functions, there is no way to resolve the value as the component can only see the wrapper, the promise.

Comment: I thought useEffect can be included for one time . But it wrong